# Calling Apps Script API function from Golang with Parameters?

Tags: go, google-apps-script, google-bigquery

I want to call Apps Script function from Golang.

I can send the Parameter from Golang but cannot make it work in `runMyFunction`. If I add `return myParameter;` - I can see the parameter 
I am passing but using it inside SQL to BigQuery is not working. I am getting `undefined`

```
var sql = ' SELECT column1, column2 ' +
  ' FROM  dataset.mytable WHERE SUBSTR ( column1) = "'
+ myParameter + '" ;'
```

### My Apps Script Function:

```
function runMyFunction(myParameter) {
...
return myParameter;
}
```

---

### In Golang, calling `runMyFunction`

```
type Message struct {
    myParameter string
}
m := Message{"1234"}
a := make([]interface{}, 1)
a[0] = m
req := script.ExecutionRequest{Function: "runMyFunction",
    Parameters: a,
    DevMode:    true}

// Make the API request.
resp, err := srv.Scripts.Run(scriptID, &req).Do()
```

---

Answer (score 1):

Actually this is the right solution:

```
a := []interface{}{"1234"}
req := script.ExecutionRequest{Function: "runMyFunction",
Parameters: a,
DevMode:    true}
```